# What year will monero be fully mined?

Tags: mining, emission-curve

In what year will monero be fully mined? I know about the .6 xmr tail emissions, but when will the last bulk of the xmr be mined?

Comment: The linked duplicate answer looks incorrect. See thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/512kwh/useful_for_learning_about_monero_coin_emission/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting https://src.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/tail-emission.html:

> Monero block rewards will never drop to zero. Block rewards will gradually drop until tail emission commences at the end of May 2022. At this point, rewards will be fixed at 0.6 XMR per block.